# Normalize angle and length in c#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Does anyone know how to normalize angle to [0,360] and length to [0,1] in c#.

please refer the link below, I'm trying to implement the second step in the answer.

[how should I use the velX,velY information to get the displacement in X and Y between current frame and previous frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014776/how-should-i-use-the-velx-vely-information-to-get-the-displacement-in-x-and-y-be)

```
 angle1 = Math.Atan2(h.Intensity, g.Intensity);
 if(angle1 < 0)
 {
       angle1 += 2 * Math.PI;
 }
```

Is this the right way, Any suggestions please? Can i use Math.round function instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to do this:

```
displacement = velocity * timestep
```

If you have 60Hz video, for example, then `timestep` is `1/60`.